# How do i restore initial blog view if i accidentally deleted it?

Tags: web-part, blog

I have a created a blog sub site in SP, which have a posts list with preview of each post as shown below (got the image from other site):

[Initial Blog View](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/2010-04-29-SPBlogPlatformEnhancements2010-10.png)

However due to my butter fingers, i have accidentally removed the post list web part. Hence I attempt to add it back. Now the post list appears as follows, each post doesn't have the preview anymore:

[After Adding Back Post List View](http://www.misdivision.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Use-Access-to-Edit-lists-in-Sharepoint-Slide-02.png)

How do i revert back to the initial view where the posts list will display the preview of each post without using Sharepoint Designer (I have no rights to install designer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

1. Edit your page (where your default view is broken)
2. Add new webpart
3. Select the posts list from section "Lists and Libraries"
4. Once the webpart has been added change the selected view to summary view.

If that doesn't work try to reset the blog to site definition with powershell

```
    $web = Get-SPWeb "http://your-blog-site"
    $DebugPreferences = "Continue"
    Write-host "Resetting all pages in site ($web.Url))."
    $web.RevertAllDocumentContentStreams()
    $web.Dispose()
```

Good Luck!